# Mysql getConnection() doesn't return the callback function in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, database

I am trying to get a connection from mysql connection pool in nodejs. But the getConnection method for the pool does not return the callback function. (so it doesn't show any error or return the connection). But my mysql workbench shows that a connection has been made. Still when I using the connection it doesn't return anything in the callback.

```
   var pool = mysql.createPool({
      connectionLimit: 10,
      host: "localhost",
      database: "database",
      user: "root",
      password: "password"
   });

   exports.query = function (query, params, callback) {
      pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        if (err) {

            console.log(err);
            connection.release();
            callback(err.code, null);
        }
        console.log("connected");
        connection.query(query, params, function (err, results) {
            connection.release();
            if (!err) {
                callback(null, results);

            }
            else {

                callback(err.code, null);

            }

        });

        connection.on('error', function (err) {
            connection.release();
            callback(err.code, null);
        });

    });
```

}

This is where I query using the database.

```
 exports.getLevels= function(callback){
    var query = 'SELECT * FROM levels';
    db.query(query,null, function (err, results) {
       if (err) {
          console.log(err);
       }
       console.log('reached');
       callback(err, results);
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this one this might help**

I'm using this npm package
[mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) using this command

```
npm i --save mysql
```

I think either you doý have a localhost user and remote user or you mysql instance is not running. Make sure you have create a local user which you access in nodejs script, you can take help from [here](https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/mysql/managing-mysql-databases-and-users-from-the-command-line) and check connection from using [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-node-mysql-javascript-client/).

```
const MySQL_DB = require( "mysql" );
let DB_Pool = MySQL_DB.createPool( {
    connectionLimit: 15,
    multipleStatements: true,
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "abcdefgh",
    database: "working_db",
    port: "3306"
} );

function GetDatabaseResponse( query ) {

    return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
        DB_Pool.getConnection( ( ConnectionErrorMessage, DB_LocalConnection ) => {
            if ( ConnectionErrorMessage ) {
                console.log( "DataBase Connection Failed" );
                console.log( ConnectionErrorMessage );
                resolve( ConnectionErrorMessage );
                return;

            } else {

                DB_LocalConnection.query( query, ( ProcedureErrorMessage, ProcedureCallResult ) => {
                    DB_LocalConnection.release();
                    if ( ProcedureErrorMessage ) {
                        console.log( "DataBase Query Execution Failed" );
                        console.log( DB_ProcedureCall );
                        console.log( ProcedureErrorMessage );
                        resolve( ProcedureErrorMessage );
                        return;

                    } else {
                        resolve( ProcedureCallResult );
                        return;
                    }
                } );
            }
        } );
    } );
}

( async () => {
    let query = 'SELECT * FROM levels';
    let Result = await GetDatabaseResponse( query );
    console.log( Result );
} )();
```

**Here are your code implementation its working fine on my side.**

**databaseFile.js**

```
const mysql = require( "mysql" );
var pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 15,
    multipleStatements: true,
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "abcdefgh",
    database: "working_db",
    port: "3306"
 });

module.exports =( query, callback) => { 

    pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
      if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          connection.release();
          callback(err.code, null);
      }
      console.log("connected");
      connection.query(query,  (err, results) => {
          connection.release();
          if (!err) {
              callback(null, results);
          }
          else {
              callback(err.code, null);
          }
      });

      connection.on('error',(err) => {
          connection.release();
          callback(err.code, null);

      });

  });
}
```

**index.js**

```
let GetBataBaseResponse = require("./databaseFile");

GetBataBaseResponse("Select * from tblagents",(error, result) => {
    console.log("error",error);
    console.log("result",result);
});
```

If you still have issue message me.

Comment: It seems that I can't wrap `pool.getConnection` inside a function. When I run it outside a function on its own the the callback was returned. (That means I added `pool.getConnection` right after creating the pool just to see what happens and it works fine but not this way.

Comment: I can connect to the pool inside the same file that `getResponse` method is in. I can access it from another local function also (I can call  `getResponse` method from another local function. But once I export that function it stops connecting properly.

Comment: I have update the answer.  When I use wrong credentials then its crashed. But this implementation with correct credentials are working fine.

Comment: I tried this. It works as long as I directly query the database like you have done. But if I try doing the same thing inside a function that is exported, the callbacks doesn't return. I've updated my question to show where I use the database query inside the exported function.